# Serialzing POCO EF Objects in Workflow Persistance

Tags: entity-framework, workflow, poco

I am trying to persist a workflow that has a EF POCO in it as a variable.  When I try to persist (and workflow is trying to serialize the object), I get an error:

> Type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[MyObject]' cannot be
>   serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute
>   attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider
>   marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[Get serialization error when try and submit EF4 entity via WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279434/get-serialization-error-when-try-and-submit-ef4-entity-via-wcf)

It turns out the FixupCollection (in Entities.tt) does not have the DataContract attribute.  Once I added that, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Turning it into a list is probably the easiest way to get around this. The problem is it doesnt know how to serialise your collection

Comment: Can you finish your comment?  It seems like the data contract serializer works because I can serialize it outside of workflow.